# Is there a way to run AT-COMMAND programmatically in Android?

Tags: at-command

I need to retrieve signal quality parameters such as channel bit error rate, received signal code power, ratio of the received energy per PN chip and reference signal received quality. So is it possible to run AT-COMMAND : +CESQ that returns these informations above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program. My phone does not have the AT+CESQ command, but issuing the AT+CSQ command from my pc is a simple as

```
$ echo AT+CSQ | atinout - /dev/ttyACM0 - 
AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 99,99

OK
$
```

Now to run this on android you need to replace /dev/ttyACM0 with an suitable device and also you need to cross compile atinout for the appropriate hardware target, but it is absolutely possible.